# Rx.NET Is there an elegant way to create observable from callback which is passed in ctor

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, rx.net

I have this code

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;

var wrapper = new Wrapper<int>();

var clicker = new Clicker(wrapper.Action);

Observable
    .FromEvent
    (
        (Action<int> f) => wrapper.RegisterCallback(f),
        f => wrapper.UnregisterCallback(f)
    )
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

clicker.Click(7);
clicker.Click(2);
clicker.Click(5);

public class Clicker
{
    private readonly Action<int> _callback;

    public Clicker(Action<int> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public void Click(int val)
    {
        _callback(val);
    }
}

public class Wrapper<T>
{
    private readonly List<Action<T>> _callbacks = new();

    public void RegisterCallback(Action<T> callback) => _callbacks.Add(callback);

    public void UnregisterCallback(Action<T> callback) => _callbacks.Remove(callback);

    public void Action(T val) => _callbacks.ForEach(f => f(val));
}
```

and I need to create an observable that reacts to Click call in Clicker. **The callback is passed in ctor**. Is there any other way of implementing that **will not require implementing the Wrapper class**.

Comment: You realize that the functionality you're implementing in the clicker and wrapper can be replaced with a subject and subscription right? Clicker is just an event source (the subject) and each added callback is a subscription to that event.

Comment: The clicker cannot be replaced. It must be used as is.

Comment: You should replace it or at the very least wrap it to use it as it should.

Comment: @JeffMercado Ah, ok. Subject is suitable to replace the wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes are trying to replicate basic functionality of delegates and observables... just use them as they are intended.

```
public class Clicker : ISubject<int>
{
    private readonly Subject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();

    public void Click(int val)
    {
        subject.OnNext(val);
    }

    public void OnCompleted() => subject.OnCompleted();
    public void OnError(Exception error) => subject.OnError(error);
    public void OnNext(int value) => subject.OnNext(value);
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer) => subject.Subscribe(observer);
    public IDisposable Subscribe(Action<int> onNext) => subject.Subscribe(onNext);
}
```

```
var clicker = new Clicker();
clicker.Subscribe(callback); // subscribe using the callback

clicker.Click(7);
clicker.Click(2);
clicker.Click(5);

clicker.OnNext(7); // equivalent
clicker.OnNext(2);
clicker.OnNext(5);
```

If you must insist on keeping the classes, create a subject in place of the clicker instance.

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();
var clicker = new Clicker(subject.OnNext);


subject.Subscribe(callback);
subject.OnNext(7);
clicker.Click(7); // equivalent
```